# Can't access form inside AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can't access form variable from my controller, when i try to access it by $scope.locationForm i've got 'undefined', but when i call console.log($scope) i can see in console there have loactionForm.

My HTML code

```
<div ng-controller="LocationsController as ctrl">   
<form class="form-inline" name="locationForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <div class="input-group"> -->
            <label for="location-name">Название населенного пункта</label>
            <input required
                   name="name"
                   ng-model="ctrl.location.name" type="text" class="form-control" id="location-name" placeholder="Название населенного пункта">
            <label for="location-name">Район</label>
            <select required
                    name="region_id" 
                    ng-model="ctrl.location.region_id" 
                    ng-options="region.id as region.name for region in ctrl.regions" class="form-control" placeholder="Название района"></select>
            <input ng-click="ctrl.save()"
                   ng-disabled="locationForm.$invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Cохранить">
            <a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.reset()" ng-show="locationForm.$dirty">Сброс</a>
        <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
</form>
```

My Controller code:

```
function LocationsController($scope, Location, Region, $q) {
var lc = this,
    l_index;
  lc.form ={};
  lc.regions = lc.locations = [];
  lc.regions = Region.query();
  lc.regions.$promise.then(function(data) {
      lc.locations = Location.query();
  });
  lc.getRegion = function (id) {
    return lc.regions.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.id == id;
    })[0].name;
  };
  console.log($scope);
  // console.log($scope.locationForm);
  lc.reset = function () {
      lc.location = new Location;
  }
  lc.reset();
```

};

Comment: I think the problem is the `LocationController` is initialized before the `form` element is compiled - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jcvqdf06/1/

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: i need a `$setPristine` method of `locationForm` to use it in the reset function

Comment: call the reset in a timeout - `$timeout(function(){lc.reset();})`

Comment: thank for a advice, but found a dummy solution. I check typeof locationForm before call it every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when the `LocationsController` is initialized the `form` element is not yet compiled. So one possible hack is to use a timeout like

```
function LocationsController($scope, Location, Region, $q, $timeout) {
    //then later
    $timeout(function(){lc.reset();})
}
```